# characters missing in the unicode standard

Tags: unicode

Occasionally I need characters that seem to be missing in the unicode standard (that is, these characters are not just missing in a font used by an application).  For example the unicode block with mathematical alphanumeric symbols lacks the MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL N, Q and R (commonly used in math to denote integer, rational, and real numbers).  See, for example, https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols/list.htm.

What is the reason for this and how can one work around it?  It seems to me that the most commonly used double-struck capital characters are missing.  (I have noticed similar issues in other unicode blocks relevant for math.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whatever happened to the Unicode Character MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012644/whatever-happened-to-the-unicode-character-mathematical-double-struck-capital-c)

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's useful.  (Sadly, this makes scripting more tedious when code points of characters in an alphabet do not go consecutively.)

Answer (score 2):

Those letters are found earlier in the [Letter-like symbols range](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/letterlike-symbols/double-struck-symbols):

- ℂ (U+2102)
- ℍ (U+210D)
- ℕ (U+2115)
- ℙ (U+2119)
- ℚ (U+211A)
- ℝ (U+211D)
- ℤ (U+2124)

Comment: I wonder why someone has downvoted this answer. The only part missing here is the reason: as in other cases, the normally used symbols have been added first. Only later their properties have been extended to the whole alphabet. This can be seen also from the codes:  is U+1D538, while ℂ is U+2102 (much lower).

Comment: Thanks! - How can one find such characters that are "misplaced" for apparently historical reasons?  Say, MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL H and I are likewise missing among the  mathematical alphanumeric symbols.

Comment: I used http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_index.html.

Comment: @WalterTross Although I didn't downvote this answer, there are several possible reasons for downvoting it: [1] The question is off topic for SO, and therefore should not be answered. [2] The question is a duplicate, and therefore should not be answered. (FWIW, that's my opinion in this case.) [3] It doesn't directly answer the questions that were asked (_"What is the reason for this and how can one work around it?"_). Questions on SO that are purely about Unicode are frequently not well received here if there is no code and no direct relationship to software development.